# Generalized compact open topology?

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, definitions

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces.  The compact-open topology on $C(X,Y)$ is generated by the sub-basic open sets 
$$
\left\{U_{K,O}: \mbox{ K is compact in X and O is open in Y}\right\}\\
U_{K,O}:=\left\{f \in C(X,Y):\, f(K')\subseteq O \right\}
.$$
However, if $X$ is not Hausdorff then sometimes this topology may be oddly-behaved.

Instead, consider this generalization (which clearly is equal to the compact-open topology when $X$ is Hausdorff) of the compact-open topology; generated by the sub-basic sets:
$$
\left\{V_{K',O}:(\exists K \subseteq X \mbox{ compact})\; K'\subseteq K, \mbox{ K is closed in X and O is open in Y}\right\}\\
V_{K',O}:=\left\{f \in C(X,Y):\, f(K')\subseteq O \right\}.
$$

Is this topology studied?  If so where?

Comment: So, equivalently, $K'$ is compact and has compact closure, right?

Comment: Exactly... Is this a studied object?